# Running Image Manipulation in run_in_executor. Adapting to multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

Hey so I run lots of Image Manipulation on an api built using fastapi async. I would like to be able to run the Image Manipulation asynchronously. As a result I used run_in_executor which I believe runs it in a seperate thread. However I was told that using python multiprocessing is better instead. Does moving have any advantages?.

```py
import asyncio
import functools

from app.exceptions.errors import ManipulationError


def executor(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            partial = functools.partial(function, *args, **kwargs)
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            return loop.run_in_executor(None, partial)
        except Exception:
            raise ManipulationError("Uanble To Manipulate Image")

    return decorator
```

I made this decorator to wrap my blocking funcs as run in executor.

two questions

a) Does moving to multiprocesisng have any advantages

b) How would I do so

Comment: If you are satisfied with this code, there is no reason to change it. Multiprocessing is indicated if you wanted the processing to utilize multiple CPU cores in addition to being asynchronous.

Comment: I would like to yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a) Does moving to multiprocesisng have any advantages

Yes, it utilizes multiple cores in case of CPU-bound processing.

> b) How would I do so

By passing an instance of `ProcessPoolExecutor` to `run_in_executor`. (The `None` value you're passing now means use the default executor provided by asyncio, which is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.) For example (untested):

```
_pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

def executor(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        return loop.run_in_executor(_pool, function, *args)

    return decorator
```

This will also require that all arguments to the function be serializable, so that they can be transferred to the subprocess.

Comment: Ran into this error @user4815162342 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733924/pickling-python-function-fails-with-processpoolexecutor-in-a-decorator lmk!

Comment: @Daggy1234 I've simplified the decorator so it avoids the use of `functools.partial` which I believe caused the issue.