# Pickling Python Function fails with ProcessPoolExecutor in a decorator

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, pickle, python-multiprocessing, fastapi

So I asked this question and tried the ProcessPoolExecutor approach. I used the decorator suggested the following way:

[Running Image Manipulation in run_in_executor. Adapting to multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671252/running-image-manipulation-in-run-in-executor-adapting-to-multiprocessing)

```py
import asyncio
import functools
from concurrent import futures

from app.exceptions.errors import ManipulationError


_pool = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()


def executor(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            partial = functools.partial(function, *args, **kwargs)
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            return loop.run_in_executor(_pool, partial)
        except Exception as e:
            raise ManipulationError(str(e))

    return decorator
```

I then used it on a function like:

```py
@executor
@pil
def blur(image):
    frame = image.convert("RGBA")
    return frame.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

Note the `@pil` is another decorator I made.

```py
def pil(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(image, *args, **kwargs) -> BytesIO:
        img = PILManip.pil_image(image)
        if img.format == "GIF":
            frames = []
            for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(img):
                res_frame = function(frame, *args, **kwargs)
                frames.append(res_frame)
            return PILManip.pil_gif_save(frames), "gif"
        elif img.format in ["PNG", "JPEG"]:
            img = function(img, *args, **kwargs)
            return PILManip.pil_image_save(img), "png"
        else:
            raise BadImage("Bad Format")

    return wrapper
```

I called it in a FastApi route like so:

```py
@router.get("/blur/", responses=normal_response)
async def blur_image(url: str):
    byt = await Client.image_bytes(url)
    img, image_format = await blur(byt)
    return Response(img.read(), media_type=f"image/{image_format}")
```

I get some error about pickling.

```py
500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 391, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 25, in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, self.call_next)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/app/middleware/timer.py", line 8, in add_process_time_header
    response = await call_next(request)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 45, in call_next
    task.result()
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 38, in coro
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 25, in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, self.call_next)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette_prometheus/middleware.py", line 56, in dispatch
    raise e from None
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette_prometheus/middleware.py", line 52, in dispatch
    response = await call_next(request)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 45, in call_next
    task.result()
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 38, in coro
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 201, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 148, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/home/codespace/workspace/dagpi-image/app/routes/image_routes.py", line 107, in blur_image
    img, image_format = await blur(byt)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 239, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/opt/python/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function blur at 0x7f87524091f0>: it's not the same object as app.image.pil_manipulation.blur
```

Does someone know why this keeps happening?
I was told the objects have to be serializable, I believe BytesIO is the only in/out of the image. That should be serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators typically produce wrapped functions that aren't easy to pickle (serialize) because they contain hidden state. When dealing with multiprocessing, you should avoid decorators and send ordinary global functions to `run_in_executor`. For example, you could re-write your `executor` decorator into a utility function:

```
_pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
 
async def exec_async(fn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(_pool, fn, *args)
```

Instead of decorating a function with `executor`, you can just await it using `await exec_async(some_function, arg1, arg2, ...)`. Likewise, you can rewrite the `pil` decorator into another utility:

```
def pil(image, transform):
    img = PILManip.pil_image(image)
    if img.format == "GIF":
        frames = []
        for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(img):
            res_frame = transform(frame)
            frames.append(res_frame)
        return PILManip.pil_gif_save(frames), "gif"
    elif img.format in ["PNG", "JPEG"]:
        img = transform(img)
        return PILManip.pil_image_save(img), "png"
    else:
        raise BadImage("Bad Format")
```

The implementation of `blur` now becomes an ordinary function which *calls* `pil`, and which can be safely passed to `exec_async`:

```
def blur(image):
    def transform(frame):
        frame = frame.convert("RGBA")
        return frame.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
    return pil(image, transform)
 
@router.get("/blur/", responses=normal_response)
async def blur_image(url: str):
    byt = await Client.image_bytes(url)
    img, image_format = await exec_async(blur, byt)
    return Response(img.read(), media_type=f"image/{image_format}")
```

Note: the above code is untested.